# Exponent of x[1, 2]^(-1/3) in Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, programming

Is there some function in Mathematica which returns exponent of a variable? For example, if the input is x[1,2]^(-1/3), then the output is -1/3. I tried the function Exponent, but it returns 0. Thank you very much.

Edit: I want to define a function f such that $f(x[1,2]^{-1/3})=-1/3$ and $f(x^{-1/3})=-1/3$, $f(x[2]^{-1/3})=-1/3$.

Comment: `Exponent[x[1, 2]^(-1/3), x[1, 2]]` worked for me.

Comment: `f[Power[_, e_]] := e`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Some Alternatives :)

Indexing the symbol tree with `Part`

```
(  x[1, 2]^(-1/3)  )[[2]]
```

[image]

```
Part[  x[1, 2]^(-1/3),   2]
```

---

Using `Log` the inverse operation:

```
Log[ x[1, 2],  x[1, 2]^(-1/3) ] // Simplify
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a rewrite rule:

```
x[1, 2]^(-1/3) /. _^x_ -> x
(* -(1/3) *)
```